# QGraphicsScene with QTableWidget with widget in cell: scrolling not working

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qgraphicsview

I have weird problem with scrolling `QTableWidget` inside `QGraphicsScene`. If I just put some text inside any cell with `setItem` method, scrolling works fine. But if I put this text in `QLabel` and set it with `setCellWidget` scrolling doesn't work. In the picture should be row and column # of current cell.

[image]

Code: https://github.com/ntfshard/SO_18-01-2021

Comment: Qt 5.15.2 (MSVC 2019, 64 bit)

Comment: Seems known bug. 

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-12253